# How To Achieve "one-way" Exchange Pattern With The new HTTP Connector In Mule?

Tags: java, mule, esb

I am quoting from [Mule official documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Migrating+to+the+New+HTTP+Connector)

> On the old HTTP Connector, both for inbound and outbound endpoints, it
> was possible to set up the exchange-pattern so that messages only went
> in one direction, so inbound endpoints would send no request back to
> the requestor, and outbound endpoints would not listen for a response
> to their requests. The new HTTP Connector always has a two way
> communication.

It seems that one-way is not an option in The new HTTP Connector, but i do need a one-way exchange pattern in my application (the whole architecture of my app and subsidiaries that mostly are services on different servers around the country) to perform code like below :

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="${MaximumRetry}" secondsBetweenRetries="${RetryInterval}">
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="${EMCURL}" exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</until-successful>
```

So what are my options in migrating to new HTTP Connectors?
I see three options

1. Find another way (maybe i shouldn't use HTTP connectors after all).
2. Find a Hacker Solution
3. Use the old http:outbound-endpoints, and stick to Mule 3.6

Which one do you suggest?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't interested in the response simply place the HTTP request in a async scope or in another flow that is called through a one way vm endpoint.

Comment: but my understanding from mule suggests that putting it in <async> does not abort the response. it will just wait for the response in other thread

Comment: True but since HTTP is a request-response by design that is the same as the old HTTP transport did when you set it to one way. The only difference with async is that your calling flow will not wait for the call to complete before continuing.

Comment: i guess this solution is and implementation of my second option:Hacker Solution :D

Comment: I don't consider it to be a hacker solution, at least not more so than what the old HTTP transport did, but instead a sensible way of handling asynchronous communication over a protocol that is by design synchronous. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: Accepted as a hacker solution ;)

Comment: What if i want to make http listener connector as one way?